# Installing the Mongo PHP Extensions (php_mongo.dll)

Tags: php, mongodb, dll, mongodb-query, mamp

Environment in  local system

```
MAMP 3.2.2
PHP 5.6.24
Webserver Apache
```

Mongodb for caching is installed successfully and found running in MongoDBservice.

I Downloaded Mongodb drivers from https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb (used thread safe versions PHP5.6 `"php_mongodb.dll"`) selected `php_mongo-1.1.8-5.6-ts-vc11-x64.zip`, Made changes to php.ini as `extension=php_mongo.dll`

I just copied and pasted .dll file in my C:\MAMP\bin\php\php5.6.24\ext
So far good... After restarting my MAMP I cannot see mongo in phpinfo ---->This is my issue

Any idea about this?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just copying the DLL file to the correct directory is not enough. You also need to add the following line to your php.ini file before the MongoDB extension is available:

```
extension=php_mongo.dll
```

After that restart Apache and MongoDB should show up as an available extension in phpinfo().

By the way, that is also mentioned on the official PHP website for installing the MongoDB driver: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.windows.php

Answer (score 2):

Should be `extension="php_mongodb.dll` instead of `extension="php_mongo.dll` as it is the name of the file you copied.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I first downloaded a x64 version of php_mongo.dll, which did not show in phpinfo page. Then i downloaded a x86 version and everything works fine. Hope this helps.

PS. Make sure you pick the right php version.